# Root and unroot Cat S41

Tags: root-access, permissions, unrooting

Does anyone knows how to root then unroot this device? I've just installed Termux emulator but I am not able to run some commands. The terminal's output comes with a "Permission denied" issue. I've talked with Caterpillar about rooting S41 so they told me that I may root this device but, in line with other manufacturers, CAT doesn't support this activity.

Comment: Based on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidroot/comments/93gjmv/rootcustom_rom_on_cat_s41_possible/) and XDA Forum ([1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/cat-s41-root-recovery-t3709177), [2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/cat-s41-to-root-device-figure-t3730027)), I don't think anyone has found a way to root it... for now. That said, perhaps you could clarify instead what are you trying to do when you get the "Permission denied"? Perhaps there's another way to solve your issue without rooting.

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/dev/net’: Permission denied. Root localhost can't access network,so I think I need a root access...Have some commands too that I can't be able to run.